# Apache Tika and Apache PDFBox 2.0

Tags: pdfbox, apache-tika

We are using tika 1.4. Now we need to use PDF Box 2.0.1 for digital signature. I can see that some of the classes of PDF box is used in tika. Is Pdf box part of tika? If so, I needn't add pdf box separately. do I? Is tika 1.13 backward compatible with tika 1.4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first version of Apache Tika to bundle Apache PDFBox 2.0 was Apache Tika 1.13, as shown in the [Apache Tika latest news on the project homepage](http://tika.apache.org/)

Versions of Apache Tika are generally backwards compatible, any issues are noted in the [release changes file](http://www.apache.org/dist/tika/CHANGES-1.13.txt)

It isn't possible to use PDFBox 2.0 with an old version of Tika like 1.4. If you want to use the latest PDFBox, you must upgrade to a matching newer Tika version

So, you should upgrade your Apache Tika version to a newer one like 1.13, *and* upgrade all of the Tika dependencies